# I've pickle files already uploaded in google drive. How can I use it in Google Colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-drive-api, drive, google-colaboratory

I already have pickle files worth of 300-400MBs in the google drive's Colab folder.

I want to read use it in Google colab, but unable to do it?

I tried

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

#print(uploaded)
for name, data in uploaded.items():
  with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    #f.write(data)
    print ('saved file', name)
```

But, it prompts to upload.

I already gave access to drive using:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Do I need to give access permission again??

Why it shows only *datalab* in folder?

```
$ !ls
> datalab
```

Do I need doanload the file again to the google colab notebook ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Python and change the current directory. For e.g.,

```
import os
os.chdir('datalab')
```

will take you inside the `datalab` folder. If you run `!ls` now, you will see the contents of the `datalab` folder. Then, you can once again change directories as long as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pydrive for that. First, you need to find the ID of your file.

```
# Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Download a file based on its file ID.
#
# A file ID looks like: laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
listed = drive.ListFile({'q': "title contains '.pkl' and 'root' in parents"}).GetList()
for file in listed:
    print('title {}, id {}'.format(file['title'], file['id']))
```

You can then load the file using the following code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

import io
import pickle
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

file_id = 'laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz'

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
    # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
    _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
f = pickle.load(downloaded)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to mount your Google Drive locally.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
!ls # will show you can now access the gdrive locally
```

This mounts your google drive to the notebook so you can access documents in your google drive as if they were local. To access the "Colab Notebooks" part of your google drive use the following path:

```
GDRIVE_DIR = "gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/"
```

If you have your pickle files  in the Colab Notebooks folder then you can load them in with:

```
import os
import pickle

filename = ... # The name of the pickle file in your Google Drive
data = pickle.load(os.path.join(GDRIVE_DIR, filename))
```

A tutorial on mounting your Google Drive and other methods can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)

Comment: This answer does not provide enough information to solve the issue. Please consider all of the elements listed in the original question.